Why are logarithms used to measure Similarity?
I was reading this link on how to test the difference between 2 probability distributions :https://chjackson.github.io/kl.html.
If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are discrete distributions, the KL Divergence can be used to measure how close these two distributions are to each other:
$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_{i} P(i) \cdot log \left( \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)} \right)$$
If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are continuous distributions, the KL Divergence can be used to measure how close these two distributions are to each other:
$$
    D_{KL}(P||Q) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x) \cdot log \left( \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \right) dx$$
I have the following question: Why are we interested in the logarithm ratio of these two distributions?
For example, why don't we define the difference as the absolute differences?
$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_{i} |q(x) - p(x)|$$
$$
    D_{KL}(P||Q) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |q(x) - p(x)|  dx$$
Wouldn't this seem a lot more logical?
Can someone please help me understand this?

First you have to quantify one-distribution information.

can you please elaborate?
